# Multiple Axes on a Highcharts Heatmap

Tags: javascript, highcharts, heatmap, highmaps

**The Goal**

I am working with a Highcharts Heatmap to present data which must have two YAxis displays (on on the left and one on the right). Both are to be of the "categories" type (which is to say driven by strings, not numerical values).

**The Problem**

When multiple Y axes are defined, only the labels for the first are shown.

**The Code**

[Here is a fiddle with my code](https://jsfiddle.net/0fox9fwj/2/). I would specifically draw your attention to these lines:

```
yAxis: [{
            categories: ["For instance, on the planet Earth, man had always assumed that he was more intelligent than dolphins because he had achieved so much—the wheel, New York, wars and so on—whilst all the dolphins had ever done was muck about in the water having a good time. But conversely, the dolphins had always believed that they were far more intelligent than man—for precisely the same reasons",
                         'The man who invented the Total Perspective Vortex did so basically in order to annoy his wife.',
                         'The major problem - one of the major problems, for there are several - one of the many major problems with governing people is that of whom you get to do it; or rather of who manages to get people to let them do it to them.',
                         'My doctor says that I have a malformed public-duty gland and a natural deficiency in moral fibre',
                         'He felt uncertain as to whether the fourth drink had understood all that, so he sent down a fifth to explain the plan more fully and a sixth for moral support.'],
            title: null,
            gridLineWidth: 0,
            labels: {
                style: {
                    whiteSpace: 'nowrap',
                    textOverflow: 'ellipsis',
                    float: 'left'
                }
            }
        },{
            categories: ["1/7", "2/7", "3/7", "4/7", "5/7"],
            title: null,
            opposite: true,
            // Note: The following two lines appear to be unnecessary
            type: 'category',
            visible: true
        }],
```

Observe that the first yAxis column appears properly along the left side of the chart. Observe also that there is no visual representation of the second yAxis (which is set to appear on the right side of the graphic, between the plot and the legend).

What is interesting is if I reorder the two Y axes, the categories on the right now appear, and the ones on the left disappear. Additionally interesting; if the axes are given titles (`title: null` is removed or changed), the titles appear in the correct place.

**The Documentation**

The code seems to be perfectly in line with [the official examples for dual Y axes](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/combo-multi-axes). Even copying that sample code exactly causes the same failure. I know that the HeatMap chart type is not necessarily part of the core library, but I have found no indication that this *shouldn't* work with a Heatmap.

**Conclusion**

Any help that could be given to getting Y axis labels to display on both sides of the plot would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Interesting. If you inspect the chart you can see that you have 2 `g` compontents of class "highcharts-axis-labels highcharts-yaxis-labels" in the DOM. The second one appears to be for your second yAxis but it is an empty element in the DOM.

Comment: I observed this, which is amongst the chief reasons I suspect this is an issue between Heatmaps and the multi-axis feature (and not an error in my implementation).

Comment: Yea, I think highcharts is ignoring any extra axis assignments. Can you achieve desired result with some sort of main axis labeling?

Comment: Hmm, that's not a bad idea. I'm hesitant to do so, however, because this graphic is part of a large library of similarly styled graphics, all of which are utilizing the appropriate Y axis labels. They definitely need to look visually consistent, and ideally they would be written in a somewhat consistent manner as well. Still, I'll play with that, and keep it in my pocket should the need arise.

Comment: How about setting linkedTo parameter, https://jsfiddle.net/3zun7pz4/ ?

Comment: Thank you, Sebastian! That is exactly what I needed. If you turn that into an answer I'll upvote and accept it (if you don't, I'll key it in myself and accept it).

Comment: @ConnorCMcKee I did ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [linkedTo](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.linkedTo) parameter.

```
yAxis: [{
        type: 'category',
            categories: ["For instance, on the planet Earth, man had always assumed that he was more intelligent than dolphins because he had achieved so much—the wheel, New York, wars and so on—whilst all the dolphins had ever done was muck about in the water having a good time. But conversely, the dolphins had always believed that they were far more intelligent than man—for precisely the same reasons", 'The man who invented the Total Perspective Vortex did so basically in order to annoy his wife.', 'The major problem - one of the major problems, for there are several - one of the many major problems with governing people is that of whom you get to do it; or rather of who manages to get people to let them do it to them.', 'My doctor says that I have a malformed public-duty gland and a natural deficiency in moral fibre', 'He felt uncertain as to whether the fourth drink had understood all that, so he sent down a fifth to explain the plan more fully and a sixth for moral support.'],
            title: null,
            gridLineWidth: 0,
            labels: {
                style: {
                    whiteSpace: 'nowrap',
                    textOverflow: 'ellipsis',
                    float: 'left'
                }
            }
        },{
        linkedTo: 0,
            categories: ["1/7", "2/7", "3/7", "4/7", "5/7"],
            title: null,
            opposite: true,
            // Note: The following two lines appear to be unnecessary
            type: 'category',
            visible: true
        }],
```

Example:

- https://jsfiddle.net/3zun7pz4/